# Add label at the top af a barplote using a diferent column - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe in R

```
#creating a dataset
codigo <- paste0("COD", sprintf("%03d", 1:4))
vgene <- paste0("VG", LETTERS[1:8])
set.seed(123)
codigo <- sample(codigos, 40, replace = TRUE)
vgene <- sample(vgene, 40, replace = TRUE)
datos_vgene <- data.frame(codigo, vgene)

 codigo        vgene
1  COD001   VGG
2  COD002   VGG
3  COD003   VGC
4  COD004   VGF
# … with 36 more rows
```

I would like to create a percent bar plot, for that I calculated the proportions of vgene for each "codigo" as follows:

```
vgene_group <-
  datos_vgene %>%
  group_by(codigo, vgene) %>%
  summarise(conteo = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = conteo/sum(conteo)*100) %>%
  arrange(desc(conteo)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # Deseleccionar el agrupamiento para permitir la reordenación
  mutate(vgene = reorder(vgene, freq))

# A tibble: 24 × 4
   codigo vgene conteo  freq
   <chr>  <fct>  <int> <dbl>
 1 COD001 VGC        4    40
 2 COD004 VGF        4    40
 3 COD001 VGG        2    20
# … with 20 more rows
```

When creating the bar plot, I wanted to place the absolute (not percentage) value corresponding to each group on top of each bar. I set up de column "conteo" to show the labels, this column contain the absolute count of each "codigo". I did this by adding the following line to my plot:

```
  geom_text( aes(label = after_stat(conteo), group = codigo),  stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1)
```

This line should allow me to place the aggregated sum of the "conteo" column on top of the bar, however it gives me an error. The code for the barplot with the error is shown below:

```
ggplot(vgene_group, aes(x = reorder(as.factor(codigo), -freq, FUN = sum), y = freq, fill = vgene)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("codigos") +
  ylab("V-gene expression(%)") +
  geom_text( aes(label = after_stat(conteo), group = codigo), 
             stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  )

Error in after_stat(conteo) : object 'conteo' not found
```

The error indicates that it cannot find the column "conteo", however the column is part of my dataframe. If I replace "conteo" with "y", the sum of the percentage values is plotted perfectly, but I would like to show the absolute values contained in the "conteo" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to achieve your desired result would be to use a summarized dataset for `geom_text`, i.e. to compute the counts outside of `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

vgene_group_label <- vgene_group |>
  group_by(codigo) |>
  summarise(across(c(freq, conteo), sum), .groups = "drop")

ggplot(vgene_group, aes(x = reorder(codigo, -freq, FUN = sum), y = freq, fill = vgene)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("codigos") +
  ylab("V-gene expression(%)") +
  geom_text(
    data = vgene_group_label,
    aes(label = conteo, fill = NULL), vjust = -1
  )
```

[image]

However, if you want to compute the counts on the fly you could do so using `stage` and `after_stat` like so:

```
ggplot(vgene_group, aes(x = reorder(codigo, -freq, FUN = sum), y = freq, fill = vgene)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("codigos") +
  ylab("V-gene expression(%)") +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      y = stage(conteo, after_stat = 100),
      label = after_stat(y), group = codigo
    ),
    vjust = -1,
    stat = "summary", fun = sum
  )
```

[image]